# How does the USA evaluates "EB-1 visa" specially for the students who work in a big collaboration?

Tags: usa, visa

I'm a Ph.D. student in Physics and an F1 student from Srilanka. I'm working in a big collaboration (70~80 people and they are from different universities) where we expect to have our first publication after 3 years. We are expecting a couple of publications (2~3) during that time and at the same time. I will have my name as a co-author with all other collaborators.  It means, we put all collaborator's names in the paper.

My question is how my research work could help me to get the EB1 visa in the USA? What are the most contributing factors that help to get a green card? Since I have a couple of years, any good suggestions would be helpful.